# Tomcat v7.0 Load Exception - Marking servlet ssi as unavailable

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

New install of Tomcat v7.0 and Eclipse. Attempting to load SSI Servlet support. Have modified context.xml and web.xml as per Tomcat instructions.

Context.xml (relevant fragments shown):

```
<Context reloadable="true" privileged="true">

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>


</Context>
```

web.xml (relevant fragments shown):

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ssi</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
          org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>buffered</param-name>
          <param-value>1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>debug</param-name>
          <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>expires</param-name>
          <param-value>666</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>isVirtualWebappRelative</param-name>
          <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ssi</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.shtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

But I'm still getting the following Load Exception:

```
Mar 23, 2012 12:06:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
java.lang.SecurityException: Restricted class org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIServlet
    at 

org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.checkAccess(DefaultInstanceManager.java:548)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.checkAccess(DefaultInstanceManager.java:539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Mar 23, 2012 12:06:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet ssi as unavailable
```

I've tried everything I can think of. Can anyone advise on how to fix this?
thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I added the `privileged="true"` attribute to the context element in the `context.xml` file at the root. It solved the security exception for CGI for me.

I found that through [this site](http://tomcat7cgi.blogspot.fr/2011/12/in-this-post-i-am-do-some-cgi-testing.html).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem with a different package: cgi instead of ssi. I will walk thru the solution I found to get past the error.

As with OP, I had a clean install of Tomcat 7.0.27. I was testing CGI. Working thru the initial setup I kept getting the following:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /TestTomcatApp threw load() exception
java.lang.SecurityException: Restricted class org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet
at       org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.checkAccess(DefaultInstanceManager.java:548    )
```

which is pretty much identical to the OP except for the class involved.

I searched "Tomcat Restricted DefaultInstanceManager" and located [this java source code] [1]:

```
private void  [More ...] checkAccess(Class<?> clazz, Properties restricted) {
    while (clazz != null) {
        if ("restricted".equals(restricted.getProperty(clazz.getName()))) {
            throw new SecurityException("Restricted class" + clazz);
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
}
```

The Properties class (which can be hot-linked from the code page referenced) indicated the code was most likely reading a .properties file. So I was able to zero in on catalina.properties and catalina.policy. After a careful reading of the documentation in those two files, plus reference to the [Tomcat SecurityManager Doc][2] I realized I had to add a grant statement to the catalina.policy file:

```
// The Manager application needs access to the following packages to support the
// session display functionality. These settings support the following
// configurations:
// - default CATALINA_HOME == CATALINA_BASE
// - CATALINA_HOME != CATALINA_BASE, per instance Manager in CATALINA_BASE
// - CATALINA_HOME != CATALINA_BASE, shared Manager in CATALINA_HOME
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/manager/-" {
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.ha.session";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.manager";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.manager.util";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.util";
    **permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet";**

};
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/manager/-" {
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.ha.session";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.manager";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.manager.util";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.util";
    **permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet";
};**
```

(My additions bolded)

After restarting Tomcat the error went away.

NOTE: I realized this entire problem must be driven by the security issues of running certain modules on Tomcat. My use is purely for testing on a single machine, and no production is anticipated in this mode.

[1] http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/core/DefaultInstanceManager.java#DefaultInstanceManager.checkAccess%28java.lang.Class%29

[2] http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html#Configuring_Tomcat_With_A_SecurityManager

Answer (score 0):

So just to confirm (as this works for me):

- Download Tomcat 7.0.26 (zip)
- Unpacked
- Amended ${TOMCAT_HOME)/conf/web.xml

  - Uncommented the SSI servlet definition around line 276
  - Uncommented the SSI servlet mapping around line 370
- Amended ${TOMCAT_HOME}/conf/tomcat-users.xml

  - Added role for admin-gui
  - Added user admin with admin-gui role
- Added a simple ssi.shtml page to ${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/host-manager:

  <!--#printenv -->
- Started Tomcat, no errors, http://localhost:8080/host-manager/ssi.shtml works as expected

Finally - you are editing the context.xml of the web application, not the web.xml in ${TOMCAT_HOME}/conf folder - i guess so as your example has the WatchedResource element